# KeyDown is not working, Swift

Tags: swift, nsview, keydown

I have **override keyDown method** in class `NSView`, but `I don't get any action`.

this is how my code looks like:

```
class Rotund: NSView {

var numar: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        self.needsDisplay = true
    }
}

override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        drawCanvas1(number: CGFloat(numar), x: 0)
}
func drawCanvas1(#number: CGFloat, x: CGFloat) {
    //// Color Declarations
    let color = NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.98, green: 0.008, blue: 0.008, alpha: 1)

    //// Oval Drawing
    let ovalPath = NSBezierPath(ovalInRect: NSMakeRect(x, 34, number, number))
    color.setFill()
    ovalPath.fill()
}    
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    if theEvent.keyCode == 124 {
        println("abc")
        } else {
            println("abcd")
    }
}
```

Can some Help me figure out how should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just confirming... in your code you seem to have overriden KeyUp. So maybe, you should try changing it to:

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
if theEvent.keyCode == 124 {
    println("abc")
} else {
    println("abcd")
```

}

Comment: My mistake. Sorry, i have edited code. But still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

**You have Override the keyUp method instead of keyDown**

Please change your code from

```
override func keyUp(theEvent: NSEvent) {
if theEvent.keyCode == 124 {
    println("abc")
    } else {
        println("abcd")
}
```

to override

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
if theEvent.keyCode == 124 {
    println("abc")
    } else {
        println("abcd")
}
```

Hope it help.
If not please comment below, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I just edited the code. I was doing some other tests. But still, it's not working, either with keyDown or KeyUp

Comment: then there is no problem in your code there must be some problem in if theEvent.keyCode == 124

Comment: I have deleted if statement and I have added only println("abc"). So it shoud print "abc" for every key pressed, but still no.

Comment: i have the exact same problem. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but for those coming here looking for an answer: By default NSView doesn't accept becoming a first responder. You can't receive keyDown events until you allow the view to become a first responder:

```
override public var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { true }
```

With that in place you have a better chance of the `keyDown(:)` being called.